# How to integrate wallet payments/UPI payments like Gpay, Phonepe, Paytm using Stripe and ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, stripe-payments, asp.net-core-webapi, wallet, upi

I have found only card payment mode in the stripe API documentation.
I wanted to use Googlepay, Phonepe, Paytm kind of wallet payments/Upi payments using ASP.NET Core Web API using C#.

I have read documentation from Stripe, but without any luck.

```
try
{
    AddStripePayment newPayment = new(
            customerId,
            paymentDetails.emailAddress,
            paymentDetails.Description,
            paymentDetails.Currency,
            paymentDetails.Amount);

    return await _stripeService.AddStripePaymentAsync(newPayment, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    return null;
}
```

I want to get the correct code to write to integrate wallet payments.

Comment: Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more is off-topic here.

Comment: stripe payment portal has excellent documentation, and regardless you need to read and understand that more, because you will have to do more than that, you're sharing and if you're building a wallet system you really have to understand the platform anyway. Also they have this development setup which makes it possible to dry run everything AND they have their own support to ask this question, if this level of closeness to the solution is what you can provide right now, getting your close is their very business.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to integrate wallet and card payment, you may use Payment Element integration with the guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements

Payment Element with Payment Intent supports automatic payment methods that configured in your Dashboard.

Please note that Phonepe and Paytm are not supported by Stripe. You may refer to the list of payment methods that Stripe supports here: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/integration-options